# Is there a way to use logging in Python by specifying features, rather than severity?

Tags: python, logging

Python has the `logging` module that comes with the standard library.
It lets you define messages by severity, like `debug`, `info`, `warning`, `critical`, etc.

Sometimes, this is fine. Other times, a particular feature of my program is acting up and needs to be debugged, but is too noisy to always be printing debug messages to the screen.

In such cases, I end up doing something like:

```py
# I modify this when I want to debug a particular feature
DEBUG = {
    "feature_A": False,
    "feature_B": False,
    "feature_C": True,
    "feature_D": False,
}
...

def debug(msg, msg_type):
    if DEBUG[msg_type]:
        print(msg)

...

debug("Some debug message", "feature_C")
```

The general idea is that each print statement throughout the program must specify the feature or system it belongs to (rather than, or perhaps in addition to, the severity of the message), and will only be printed if I'm debugging that particular feature.

It would probably be cleaner for me to use `os.environ` instead of modifying the `DEBUG` variable, but that's besides the point.

Does something like this already exist in the `logging` module? Am I re-inventing the wheel? Or is this not a common use-case?

Comment: This is why you should define loggers on a per-module basis and not global. Then you can have an INI file with a section for each logger. I'm sure there is a recipe somewhere in the official Python docs

Comment: Multiple loggers?

Answer (score 1):

There is the concept of [filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) in the stdlib `logging` package which allows you to log according to attributes other than severity/level. You can use filters together with the `extra` keyword argument to logging calls to achieve the kind of filtering you need.